# How to loop declaring variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know how to loop declaring a variant.

instead of

```
            Dim Foreign_Field_1 As Variant 
          ReDim Foreign_Field_1(LBound(Foreign_Key, 1) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 1), _
                                LBound(Foreign_Key, 2) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 2))
            
            Dim Foreign_Field_2 As Variant 
          ReDim Foreign_Field_2(LBound(Foreign_Key, 1) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 1), _
                                LBound(Foreign_Key, 2) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 2))
```

with     (just an idea)

```
   dim i as integer    
    for i = 1 to 2

      Dim x As Variant
      x = "Foreign_Field_" & i  

          ReDim x(LBound(Foreign_Key, 1) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 1), _
                                LBound(Foreign_Key, 2) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 2))
             

          next i
```

meaning that i want to loop through the variable itself, so that instead of writing the same procedure more than one time just loop through the same procedure.

Foreign_Field_1, Foreign_Field_2, etc...

Hope you got the question?

This is part of a bigger code, I just need help regarding this matter solely.

any ideas?

**FullCode**

```
     Sub Get_Data_BYN()

    ' // Set Data Workplaces
        
        
        ' /  Set Data WorkBooks
    
        Dim SourceBook As Workbook
        Set SourceBook = GetWorkbook(Source)
        
        Dim TargetBook As Workbook
        Set TargetBook = ThisWorkbook
        
        
        ' /  Set Data WorkSheets
    
        Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set SourceSheet = SourceBook.Worksheets("Data")
        
        Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
        Set TargetSheet = TargetBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        
        
        ' /  Set Data Ranges
        
        Dim SourceLastRow As Long
        SourceLastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim TargetLastRow As Long
        TargetLastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        
        ' /  Set Data Keys

        Dim Primary_Key As Variant '[SourceSheet Array Store]: LAVA ID
        Primary_Key = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceSheet.Range("A2:A" & SourceLastRow).Value)
        
        Dim Foreign_Key As Variant '[TargetSheet Range Store]: LAVA ID
        Foreign_Key = TargetSheet.Range("G2:G" & TargetLastRow).Value




        ' /  Set Data Fields

            Dim Primary_Field_1 As Variant '[SourceSheet Array Store]: Bayan ID
            Primary_Field_1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceSheet.Range("B2:B" & SourceLastRow).Value)
            
            Dim Primary_Field_2 As Variant '[SourceSheet Array Store]: Bayan ID
            Primary_Field_2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceSheet.Range("C2:C" & SourceLastRow).Value)
            
            
  
            Dim Foreign_Field_1 As Variant
          ReDim Foreign_Field_1(LBound(Foreign_Key, 1) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 1), _
                                LBound(Foreign_Key, 2) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 2))
         
            Dim Foreign_Field_2 As Variant
          ReDim Foreign_Field_2(LBound(Foreign_Key, 1) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 1), _
                                LBound(Foreign_Key, 2) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 2))
                                
                                
                                
            ' / Write (Keys-IndexMatch) in Array offset Foreign_Field_1
            
            Dim i As Long
            
            For i = LBound(Foreign_Key, 1) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 1)
            
            
            Foreign_Field_1(i, 1) = Primary_Field_1( _
            WorksheetFunction.Match(Foreign_Key(i, 1), Primary_Key, 0))
            
            Foreign_Field_2(i, 1) = Primary_Field_2( _
            WorksheetFunction.Match(Foreign_Key(i, 1), Primary_Key, 0))
            
            Next i


        ' / Write (Keys-IndexMatch) in Range offset Foreign_Field_1 2
            
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H2:H" & TargetLastRow).Value = Foreign_Field_1
            
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("i2:i" & TargetLastRow).Value = Foreign_Field_2




       End Sub
```

Starting from '/  Set Data Fields

I need to loop more than once without re-writing the procedures every time for each column.

Comment: How about creating an array of arrays, and loop through the parent array, re-dimensioning the internal arrays?

Comment: In VBA, all the declarations (no matter where they are in a procedure) happen at compile-time... before the procedure is run. For that reason, most choose to place all of the Dim statements at the top of the procedure. However, you may use ReDim wherever on dynamic arrays. ReDims are executed at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, if you have a bunch of consecutively-named variables you probably should be considering arrays:

```vb
Dim ForeignFields(1 to 2), n
'...
For n = 1 to 2
    ForeignFields(n) = EmptyCopy(Foreign_Key)
Next n
'...


Function EmptyCopy(arr)
    Dim rv
    Redim rv(lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 2), lbound(arr, 2) to ubound(arr, 2))
    EmptyCopy = rv
End Function
```

Comment: answer is here to the same topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085218/loop-declaring-variables-in-arrays/65086119#65086119   @Tim-Williams